# A little bit confused about group rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-rings

According to Wikipedia:

> Let G be a group, written multiplicatively, and let $R$ be a ring. The group ring of $G$ over $R$, which we will denote by $R[G]$ (or simply $RG$), is the set of mappings $f : G \to R$ of finite support, where the module scalar product $\alpha f$ of a scalar $\alpha$ in $R$ and a vector (or mapping) $f$ is defined as the vector $x\mapsto \alpha \cdot f(x)$.

My current understanding is that the set $R[G]$ contains all the possible mappings $f : G \to R$ with the following property: $f(x)= 0$ for all but finitely many $x\in G$. I'm not sure how to interpret "the module scalar product $\alpha f$ of a scalar $\alpha$ in $R$ and a vector (or mapping) $f$ ".
Moreover, what is the domain of these mappings? The group $G$ itself?

The product of two mappings $f$ and $g$ is defined as:
$x\mapsto \sum\limits_{u\in G}{f\left( u \right)g\left( {{u}^{-1}}x \right)}=\sum\limits_{uv=x}{f\left( u \right)g\left( v \right)}$.
I understand that, for instance, $f\left( u \right)\ne 0$ only for a finite number of $u$'s, therefore this definition is legitimate. What I don't understand is why those two definitions are equal.

Comment: small typo in your post , but you mean to say "$f(x)=0$ for all but finitely many $x\in G$", not $f(x)\neq 0$ :)

Comment: You're absolutelly right. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not sure how to interpret "the module scalar product αf of a scalar α in R and a vector (or mapping) f ".

This is just an intricate way to say that $\alpha\cdot f$ is the function $\alpha f$ (defined in the last part of your sentence).

> Moreover, what is the domain of these mappings? The group G itself?

Yes.

> What I don't understand is why those two definitions are equal.

Well, just set $v=u^{-1}x$ (if if $uv=x$, then $v=u^{-1}x$ ande vice versa).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Of course, I understand that if and only if $x=uv$ then ${{u}^{-1}}x={{u}^{-1}}uv$, ${{u}^{-1}}x=v$, therefore $\left( fg \right)\left( x \right)=\sum\limits_{u\in G}{f\left( u \right)g\left( {{u}^{-1}}x \right)}=\left( fg \right)\left( uv \right)=\sum\limits_{uv=x}{f\left( u \right)g\left( v \right)}$. I'm wondering why $u\in G$ changes to $uv=x$ in the summation?
By the way, if G is not commutative, then also RG is not commutative (regardless of R)?

Comment: @Gabrielė you asked the question about the commutativity a couple of weeks ago and accepted an answer! We have to change to $uv=x$ to make clear what we are summing over. In this case just all the u's and v's that have this property. Otherwise one might get the idea of iterating over all possible $u$ and $v$ or something like that.

Comment: CPCH, thank you! Yes, I realized my last question was pointless. If the group G is non-commutative then R[G] is also non-commutative, regardless of the ring R.